# Sorting characters by count using PHP or Python

Tags: php, python

I have a string of characters

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_`

I want to take this string of characters and sort them by the number of times they appear in a large block of characters. For example:

`cwrxwzbgickpjbp_svnudntddwdqbfgzyiqpuxddmpvyfquosmicfzkjekxzchngpqaksafulateukuwomdrwza_n_ptzktjzcuibnebe_tqessrzqewgkadrkvtyznaupodanwazopg_fijcoojojbsolr_ejesukzc_quochdnmti_lkvrsegyieqlqysuxdvetkqtkhxaiypfdiddztlicjurnllriopdtuuzpryrsepfydyeg_xkr_ruxp_lgqesysidfsygztwrba_ay_gaqqklbrvr_lbhawjraqujfxptmuvqfzklfodgaqrnhjravksjwemoosdlxtvw_qspxmlvqryusfixzlkb_p_c_tepzozzwnokvqspkizygoqpbhjnsxopchzgapctowbrletrunlgnvzpfwrqgedo_s_ygkxz_mpncnve_gfpbotupawevhfxvqhwlerupjfibosbvhiijrodigzyhy_iijes_xsqorshhdzkjqitpljsftpitjetwmzqiabyiewgtbjaddtsjkckcxxvlyrchloetluxkohn_uihkdjpcqgvejanslakmwendgkmvmayknvjjnr_kdapnumwvz__lsimxdtrflyleykxejl_jbkhexpcyreoapelqzzyriyrbxdgbgwrrxlj_pt_mpwubvbveakxfsbfgj___`

I also want to drop any characters after and including the underscores once I have these sorted.

Is recursion the right idea I need to look at here?

**EDIT**

Example of what may be output:

afiskjweocnsdkspwjrhfg

Basically the characters will simply be sorted based on their frequency in a single line.

Comment: A recursive solution doesn't really spring to mind, no.

Comment: It would help to see what you expect the result to be given that input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$text = 'ahugechunkofatext';
$charCounts = count_chars($text, 1);
arsort($charCounts);

$chars = array_map('chr', array_keys($charCounts));
$chars = array_filter($chars, function ($char) {
    return !in_array($char, ['_']); // A list of chars that you don't want
});

echo implode('', $chars) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `collections.Counter` to count the characters in the big string:

```
import collections
walloftext = """cwrxwzbgickpjbp_svnudntddwdqbfgzyiqpuxddmpvyfquosmicfzkjekxzchngpqaksafulateukuwomdrwza_n_ptzktjzcuibnebe_tqessrzqewgkadrkvtyznaupodanwazopg_fijcoojojbsolr_ejesukzc_quochdnmti_lkvrsegyieqlqysuxdvetkqtkhxaiypfdiddztlicjurnllriopdtuuzpryrsepfydyeg_xkr_ruxp_lgqesysidfsygztwrba_ay_gaqqklbrvr_lbhawjraqujfxptmuvqfzklfodgaqrnhjravksjwemoosdlxtvw_qspxmlvqryusfixzlkb_p_c_tepzozzwnokvqspkizygoqpbhjnsxopchzgapctowbrletrunlgnvzpfwrqgedo_s_ygkxz_mpncnve_gfpbotupawevhfxvqhwlerupjfibosbvhiijrodigzyhy_iijes_xsqorshhdzkjqitpljsftpitjetwmzqiabyiewgtbjaddtsjkckcxxvlyrchloetluxkohn_uihkdjpcqgvejanslakmwendgkmvmayknvjjnr_kdapnumwvz__lsimxdtrflyleykxejl_jbkhexpcyreoapelqzzyriyrbxdgbgwrrxlj_pt_mpwubvbveakxfsbfgj___"""
wallcount = collections.Counter(walloftext)
```

Then use these counts to sort the original alphabet:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_"
sortedalph = sorted(alphabet, key=lambda c: wallcount[c])
```

(This sorts by increasing frequency: the result has the least-frequent letter first. If you want it the other way around, throw in a `-` before `wallcount` in the lambda.)

Finally, join the sorted alphabet back into a string and chop off the underscore and everything after it:

```
finalalph = "".join(sortedalph).split("_")[0]
```