# How to create and fill a new associative array with values created in a for each?

Tags: php

I am a noob attempting to solve a program for a word search app I am doing. My goal is to take a string and compare how many times each letter of that string appears in another string. Then put that information into an array of key value pairs, where the key is each letter of the first string and the value is the number of times. Then order it with ar(sort) and finally echo out the value of the letter that appears the most (so the key with the highest value).

So it would be something like array('t' => 4, 'k' => '9', 'n' => 55), echo the value of 'n'. Thank you.

This is what I have so far that is incomplete.

```
 <?php

        $i = array();

        $testString= "endlessstringofletters";

        $testStringArray = str_split($testString);

        $longerTestString= "alphabetalphabbebeetalp
habetalphabetbealphhabeabetalphabetalphabetalphbebe
abetalphabetalphabetbetabetalphabebetalphabetalphab
etalphtalptalphabetalphabetalbephabetalphabetbetetalphabet";


            foreach ($testStringArray AS $test) {

                $value = substr_count($longerTestString, $testStringArray );

              /* Instead of the results of this echo, I want each $value to be matched with each member of the $testStringArray and stored in an array.  */
             echo $test. $value;    

        }
/* I tried something like this outside of the foreach and it didn't work as intended */
$i = array_combine($testStringArray , $value);

            print_r($i);
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this is an exact duplicate, but this reminds me a lot of [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733941/sorting-characters-by-count-using-php-or-python)

Comment: what is $alphabet? I cant see it being declared anywhere

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp will show you array syntax, look at associative array.  This will allow you to replace that echo statement.

Comment: Deleted, deleted, deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are after, then it's as simple as this:

```
<?php

    $shorterString= "abc";

    $longerString= "abccbaabaaacccb";

    //  Split the short sring into an array of its charachters
    $stringCharachters = str_split($shorterString);

    // Array to hold the results
    $resultsArray = array();

    // Loop through every charachter and get their number of occurences
    foreach ($stringCharachters as $charachter) {
        $resultsArray[$charachter] = substr_count($longerString,$charachter);
    }

    print_r($resultsArray);
```